# What's the real name and way to implement the new "Card" style modal views in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift3, modalviewcontroller

A lot of apps are now using a modal view that's mostly as high as the screen with rounded corners, etc.

Examples: Facebook Messenger single chat view, Apple Music play view, Overcast play view

What's the best way to implement it with all the custom stylings like multi label navigation bar, etc.?

Is it a custom modal presentation? Is it actually an action sheet?
Thanks for your ideas.

- Tobi

Comment: custom modal presentation, yes.

Answer (score -3):

No, no card style.
You must custom you uitableviewcell.
Ex: in uitableviewcell add a uiview, and set corner radius for this view